# Utilizing VC create in app delegate Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I using the [THTinderNavigationController](https://github.com/Tgy31/THTinderNavigationController). With this navigation controller 3 viewControllers(VC) are programmatically created from within the appDelegate. I'm simply stump on how to make each of those view controllers link to 3 different VCs of my own or replace them. Or perhaps replace them with ones thatI have made on my storyboard.

What is the best way to have 3 different viewControllers replace the once that have come with the THTinderNavigationController demo? I'm sure this is simple but since I'm a beginning I find solving this on my own a very elusive task.

Thanks in advance everyone, any help will be greatly appreciated.

here is what the appDelegate look like.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

THTinderNavigationController *tinderNavigationController = [[THTinderNavigationController alloc] init];

UIViewController *viewController1 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController1.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

UIViewController *viewController2 = [[UIViewController alloc] init ];
viewController2.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

UIViewController *viewController3 = [[UIViewController alloc] init];
viewController3.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

tinderNavigationController.paggedViewControllers = @[
                                               viewController1,
                                               viewController2,
                                               viewController3
                                               ];

tinderNavigationController.navbarItemViews = @[
                                               [[NavigationBarItem alloc] init],
                                               [[NavigationBarItem alloc] init],
                                               [[NavigationBarItem alloc] init]
                                               ];

[tinderNavigationController setCurrentPage:1 animated:NO];

self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.window.rootViewController = tinderNavigationController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edited*

Are you able to run this code in the simulator without any errors? If so, what shows up on simulator when you do? If not, make sure you've imported all the files from the sample project (`THTinderNavigationController.h` and `NavigationBarItem.h`) into your project as well as `AppDelegate.h`.

**Update**

Ok, so if you can run the code just fine, then to override the original view controllers in the project with ones from your storyboard, you would do the following:

1) make sure you have some view controllers in your storyboard with storyboard ids (see screen shot below).

2) instantiate your custom view controllers in code like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController3 = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Orange"];
```

*Note that "Orange" is just the storyboard id I gave to my view controller. You can pick anything you want.

3) Make sure the new view controllers are put into the `peggedViewControllers` property:

```
tinderNavigationController.paggedViewControllers = @[viewController1, viewController2, viewController3];
```

[image]

Comment: Yeah I can run the original code just fine. Now I want to customize and build on top of this "template" but having three separate view controllers I have made in the Storyboard

Comment: I updated my answer. Take a look and see if that works for you.

Comment: OMG thank you. It worked. I thought something like was what Im meant to do. I just couldn't get how to execute it correctly. Thank you very much.